# Compile sources in `src` directory to binaries in `bin` directory with CMake

Tags: cmake

My project directory contains a `CMakeLists.txt` file and `src` and `include` directories at its root. `src` also contains its own `CMakeLists.txt`, which is linked by the one at the root. Is there a way I can specify to CMake to set a default global build directory so that the syntax in `src/CMakeLists.txt` is close to the following?

```
include_directories(include)
add_executable(first main.cpp foo.cpp)
add_executable(second bar.cpp)
```

I would like this directory tree to be built:

```
CMakeLists.txt

src/
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp
    foo.cpp
    bar.cpp

include/
    ...

bin/ (or build/)
    first
    second
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

However, this won't create subdirectories inside `bin/` for each different target.

If you want that, you could create a helper function to wrap `add_subdirectories`:

```
function(my_add_executable TargetName)
  set(Files ${ARGV})
  list(REMOVE_AT Files 0)
  add_executable(${TargetName} ${Files})
  set_target_properties(${TargetName} PROPERTIES
                            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
                                "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${TargetName}")
endfunction()
```

then simply change your calls to:

```
my_add_executable(first main.cpp foo.cpp)
my_add_executable(second bar.cpp)
```

For further details, run

```
cmake --help-variable "CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY"
cmake --help-property "RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY"
cmake --help-property "RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>"
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Although I don't have a use for it yet, the directory-per-executable method is a great idea as my codebase grows and the binaries become more disorganized in a single folder. Also, I wasn't aware a reference feature was available from the `cmake` program itself.
(I remember replying earlier today, but I don't see the message, so apologies if this is a double post.)